# Can't get angular controller test to pass

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am having a hard time figuring out why http.post method is not being called within my tests, which is indicated by the message saying ~ "nothing to flush" as well as adding console.log statements to both the success and the error promise methods.

The api code does work when using the app.  This is my first angular controller test so I could be missing something simple.

I have been using David Mosher's example as a template https://github.com/davemo/lineman-angular-template/blob/master/spec/controllers/login_controller_spec.coffee

```
# controller
"use strict"

angular.module("woddlyApp").controller "SignupCtrl", ($scope, $http, $location) ->

  $scope.user = {}

  $scope.save = (user, role) ->
    user.role = role

    $http.post('/users', user)
      .success (data, status, headers, config) ->
        $location.path '/dashboard'

      .error (data, status, headers, config) ->



# tests
'use strict'

describe 'Controller: SignupCtrl', ->

  # load the controller's module
  beforeEach -> module('woddlyApp')

  # Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope, @$location, @$httpBackend) ->
    @scope    = $rootScope.$new()
    @redirect = spyOn($location, 'path')

    $controller 'SignupCtrl', { $scope: @scope, $location: $location }

  afterEach ->
    @$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()
    @$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()

  describe 'Successful signup', ->

    beforeEach ->
      @$httpBackend.expectPOST('/users', @scope.user).respond(200)
      @scope.save(@scope.user, 'member')
      @$httpBackend.flush()

    it 'redirects the user to the dashboard page', ->
      expect(@redirect).toHaveBeenCalledWith '/dashboard'
```

## Error

```
Chrome 28.0 (Linux) Controller: SignupCtrl Successful signup redirects the user to the dashboard page FAILED
  Error: No pending request to flush !
      at Error (<anonymous>)
      at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/home/chris/projects/personal/woddly/client/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1195:34)
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/chris/projects/personal/woddly/client/.tmp/spec/controllers/signup.js:25:34)
  Expected spy path to have been called with [ '/dashboard' ] but it was never called.
  Error: Expected spy path to have been called with [ '/dashboard' ] but it was never called.
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/chris/projects/personal/woddly/client/.tmp/spec/controllers/signup.js:30:38)
  Error: Unsatisfied requests: POST /users
      at Error (<anonymous>)
      at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (/home/chris/projects/personal/woddly/client/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1228:13)
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/chris/projects/personal/woddly/client/.tmp/spec/controllers/signup.js:19:32)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to verify that the save method actually gets called? Checked the console for error messages?

Comment: I didn't add breakpoints, but I did add some console.log statements both before and after the $http.post call and the are both fired during the test

Comment: Do you have the compiled javascript? I haven't touched CoffeeScript for a few years... If I read the code correctly I am every bit as confused as you but if you have an easy way to compile it to JS and put it on pastebin or a github gist or something I might have more luck.

Comment: After getting some help from +google it seems that the issue that I am using angular-unstable v.1.1.7. Once I figure out if this can be worked around I will post back.  Thanks for the help ivami.

Comment: Well, I didn't get to provide much help other than saying the code looks right :) You probably also want to make sure you have the same release version of angular and angular-mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I am using angular 1.1.5 (for the new ng-animate).  To get my tests passing I needed to install the angular-mocks 1.1.5.

```
bower install angular-mocks-unstable
```

or update the bower.js (or components.js) file and run:

```
bower install
```

And update my karma.conf.js file

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/components/angular-unstable/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks-unstable/angular-mocks.js',   // need unstable here
  '.tmp/scripts/*.js',
  '.tmp/scripts/**/*.js',
  '.tmp/spec/**/*.js'
];
```